# Facebook SDK login works but then closes app after

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have an app that has its own login system, where by the user enters a email and password and it checks against a remote MySql server, logs the user in if it finds the user otherwise asks them to register.

I am know trying to integrate Facebook so that the user can press a button and login with their Facebook account. 
I have found the "android simple facebook" library https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

And am trying to use this to integrate Facebook with my app. I have the below code so far, and everything seems to work however after the user logs into facebook my app just closes.
So far I have the below code:

```
SimpleFacebookConfiguration configuration = new SimpleFacebookConfiguration.Builder()
        .setAppId("*******8")
        .setNamespace("********")
        .setPermissions(permissions)
        .build();

        SimpleFacebook.setConfiguration(configuration);

        fblogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                OnLoginListener onLoginListener = new SimpleFacebook.OnLoginListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onFail(String reason)
                    {
                        Log.w(TAG, reason);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onException(Throwable throwable)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onThinking()
                    {
                        // show progress bar or something to the user while login is happening
                        Log.i(TAG, "In progress");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLogin()
                    {
                        // change the state of the button or do whatever you want
                        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNotAcceptingPermissions()
                    {
                        Log.w(TAG, "User didn't accept read permissions");
                    }

                };
                mSimpleFacebook.login(onLoginListener);
            }
        });
    }
```

Where:

```
Permissions[] permissions = new Permissions[]
            {
                Permissions.EMAIL,
            };
```

When the user clicks the fblogin button the facebook login popup comes up, the user can login and allow my app access to their information, and then the popup closes and so does my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this - https://gist.github.com/vishalpawale/5560725

It is basic skeleton for logging in with facebook-android sdk.

Comment: The thing is all I want to do is get the facebook users email and then let my login system handle it not use facebooks login flow, so something along the lines of they login using facebook, facebook gives the email and then my app actually uses that email to login

Comment: Yes so for getting users email, you need user to login with facebook and once user is logged in you can request for email, see line 114 of the gist